# backspace makes autocomplete disappear until I have retyped entire text

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

When using the autocomplete feature in TexStudio, I am facing this strange problem. Usually, autocomplete suggests me the right suggestions and closes the parantheses after pressing "Enter". E.g. I type "\cite{I", it shows me the right suggestions as below:

[image]

However, I type "\cite{ISLR}" and for some reason, delete the "R", look for autocomplete, it does not show any suggestions.

[image]

The same issue repeats for \ref as well. Some user on Reddit report this issue in the comments section of [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/jw1bpp/texstudio_autocomplete_broken/).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to retype the whole key. You can reenable auto-completion from any point in the string using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (this works for every type of auto-completion in TeXstudio).